# ExtraTreesRegressor criterion

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, ensemble-learning

As I understand, `ExtraTreesRegressor` from `sklearn` works by doing random splits instead of minimizing a metric like gini for classification or mae for regression.

I don't understand why there's a `criterion` parameter, as the criterion for the splits should be random.

Is it just for code compatibility, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood what about these splits is random. According to the [User Guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#forest) for Extremely Randomized Trees:

> As in random forests, a random subset of candidate features is used, but instead of looking for the most discriminative thresholds,
>
> **thresholds are drawn at random for each candidate feature**
>
> *and*
>
> **the best of these randomly-generated thresholds is picked as the splitting rule**.

The additional randomization of the `ExtraTreesRegressor` concerns the *thresholds* of the candidate features. But it must still be determined which of them provides the best split. And this is why you still need a `criterion` specifying the function to evaluate the quality of a split.